# Filtering elements of a numpy array depending on their occurrences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

i have the following 2D numpy array M

```
M = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
              [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
```

which I want to identify its spots (Pixels with value==1 and connected to each other).

Thanks to the function 'label' from scipy, I can identify all of my spots in the matrix. The output should seem like this:

```
Output, Nbr= label(M)
#Output=  array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#                [4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#                [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#                [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want only to have spots with 9 elements, that means the first and fourth spot.

using a for loop like this works fine:

```
for i in range(Nbr+1):
    Spot= np.argwhere(components[:,:]== i)
    if len(Spot)!=9:
        M[Spot[:, 0], Spot[:, 1]]=0
#M=  array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The porblem is when my Spots are more than 4, my code is slower.

Is there any faster alternative that can do the job of the for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Not a big improvement, but [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label) directly returns the number of features. Check also `labeled_comprehension` and `find_objects` in the same library